# How to scrape football results from sofascore using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on this project on Python 3.8. I have to download data into a Pandas Dataframe and ultimately write to a databse (SQL or Access) for all premier league teams for 2018 & 2019. I am trying to use beautifulsoup for that.
I have a code that works with soccerbase.com but it does not work on sofascore.com @oppressionslayer has helped with the code so far.
Can anybody please help me?

```
import json

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://www.sofascore.com/football///json"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
json_object = json.loads(r.content)

json_object['sportItem']['tournaments'][0]['events'][0]['homeTeam']['name']
# 'Sheffield United'

json_object['sportItem']['tournaments'][0]['events'][0]['awayTeam']['name']  # 'Manchester United'

json_object['sportItem']['tournaments'][0]['events'][0]['homeScore']['current']
# 3

json_object['sportItem']['tournaments'][0]['events'][0]['awayScore']['current']

print(json_object)
```

How do I loop this code to get the entire universe of teams?
My aim is to get every team data with rows as ["Event date", "Competition", "Home Team", "Home Score", "Away Team", "Away Score", "Score"]
e.g. 31/10/2019 Premier League Chelsea 1 Manchester United 2 1-2

I am a sarter and how can I get it?

Comment: hmmm, what does it mean it doesn't work? Wrong result? Does it crash?

Comment: You don't need beautifulsoup to download CSV data.  You should check out the "requests" package.

Comment: I get the output as "Process finished with exit code 0"

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 I meant to download in a csv file. I am not sure if sofascore has CSV .

Comment: I updated mine with yours, it combines the data in one tree, i hope you like it. thx, this is awesome btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code just works. 
Although it does not capture all database of the website but ith is a potent scraper

```
import simplejson as json
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://www.sofascore.com/football///json"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
json_object = json.loads(r.content)

headers = ['Tournament', 'Home Team', 'Home Score', 'Away Team', 'Away Score', 'Status', 'Start Date']
consolidated = []
for tournament in json_object['sportItem']['tournaments']:
    rows = []
    for event in tournament["events"]:
        row = []
        row.append(tournament["tournament"]["name"])
        row.append(event["homeTeam"]["name"])
        if "current" in event["homeScore"].keys():
            row.append(event["homeScore"]["current"])
        else:
            row.append(-1)
        row.append(event["awayTeam"]["name"])
        if "current" in event["awayScore"].keys():
            row.append(event["awayScore"]["current"])
        else:
            row.append(-1)
        row.append(event["status"]["type"])
        row.append(event["formatedStartDate"])
        rows.append(row)
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=headers)
    consolidated.append(df)

pd.concat(consolidated).to_csv(r'Path.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',
                               index=False)
```

Courtesy Praful Surve [@praful-surve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1915786/praful-surve)

Comment: Thank you for your code. After running the code I am getting error:                                                simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0).          This is the code causing the error: "json_object = json.loads(r.content)"

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://www.soccerbase.com/teams/home.sd'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
teams = soup.find('div', {'class': 'headlineBlock'}, text='Team').next_sibling.find_all('li')

teams_dict = {}
for team in teams:
    link = 'https://www.soccerbase.com' + team.find('a')['href']
    team = team.text

    teams_dict[team] = link

consolidated = []
for k, v in teams_dict.items():
    print('Acquiring %s data...' % k)

    headers = ['Team', 'Competition', 'Home Team', 'Home Score', 'Away Team', 'Away Score', 'Date Keep']
    r = requests.get('%s&teamTabs=results' % v)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')

    h_scores = [int(i.text) for i in soup.select('.score a em:first-child')]
    a_scores = [int(i.text) for i in soup.select('.score a em + em')]

    limit = len(a_scores)
    team = [k for i in soup.select('.tournament', limit=limit)]
    comps = [i.text for i in soup.select('.tournament a', limit=limit)]
    dates = [i.text for i in soup.select('.dateTime .hide', limit=limit)]
    h_teams = [i.text for i in soup.select('.homeTeam a', limit=limit)]
    a_teams = [i.text for i in soup.select('.awayTeam a', limit=limit)]

    df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(team, comps, h_teams, h_scores, a_teams, a_scores, dates)),
                      columns=headers)
    consolidated.append(df)

pd.concat(consolidated)(r'#your file location address sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig', index=False)
```

Comment: I updated mine based on yours to better consolidate the DF. Let me know if you like. BTW, this is awesome!

Comment: This code though captures only EPL data.. Your analysisis exactly where i am leading to. I would like the entire universe data.and I have used this code before.. it was downloading 948 teams dataset..  probably the structure of the webpage changed.

Comment: And that is why the source Sofascore is pretty reliable. I provides json and I really dont know how to loop for the entire universe they have. If I could get that/You can provide the code/Lead this.. This would be a great start towards running models in Rapidminer.

Comment: if you want to email me, working on a side project like that i'm open for it, i love stats.

Comment: Oh Yes, I would love to work on this. I think it is very beneficial. I cannot get into chat cause 19 rep. lol. my email address is harshadbarge @ gmail . com harshadbarge@gmail.com

Comment: I ran this [link](https://imgur.com/ztTYyxo) i wish my pycharm had all loaded lol.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203116/discussion-between-pynoob-and-oppressionslayer).

Comment: Hi @PyNoob and thank you for your code, but can you explain me why it captures only EPL data ? How to get all data ? or df per league ? thank you

Answer (score -1):

Start here:

```
https://www.sofascore.com/football///json
```

It gives you the scores in json format. The main page doesn't scrape that data. Meaning it's not on the main page source. This should help you get started.

You can load it like:

```
url = 'https://www.sofascore.com/football///json' 
r = requests.get(url) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
```

Here is an example how to extract data from json. Ultimately you have to use loops to iterate data where you see [0], but this should get you started on how to get data out:

```
json_object = json.loads(r.content)

json_object['sportItem']['tournaments'][0]['events'][0]['homeTeam']['name']                                                                                                                      
#'Sheffield United'  

json_object['sportItem']['tournaments'][0]['events'][0]['awayTeam']['name']                                                                                                                      #'Manchester United'

json_object['sportItem']['tournaments'][0]['events'][0]['homeScore']['current']  
#3

json_object['sportItem']['tournaments'][0]['events'][0]['awayScore']['current']  
#3
```

I hope this helps

UPDATE:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://www.soccerbase.com/teams/home.sd'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
teams = soup.find('div', {'class': 'headlineBlock'}, text='Team').next_sibling.find_all('li')

teams_dict = {}
for team in teams:
    link = 'https://www.soccerbase.com' + team.find('a')['href']
    team = team.text

    teams_dict[team] = link


team = []
comps = []
dates = []
h_teams = []
a_teams = []
h_scores = []
a_scores = []

consolidated = []
for k, v in teams_dict.items():
    print('Acquiring %s data...' % k)

    headers = ['Team', 'Competition', 'Home Team', 'Home Score', 'Away Team', 'Away Score', 'Date Keep']
    r = requests.get('%s&teamTabs=results' % v)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')

    h_scores.extend([int(i.text) for i in soup.select('.score a em:first-child')])
    limit_scores = [int(i.text) for i in soup.select('.score a em + em')]
    a_scores.extend([int(i.text) for i in soup.select('.score a em + em')])

    limit = len(limit_scores)
    team.extend([k for i in soup.select('.tournament', limit=limit)])
    comps.extend([i.text for i in soup.select('.tournament a', limit=limit)])
    dates.extend([i.text for i in soup.select('.dateTime .hide', limit=limit)])
    h_teams.extend([i.text for i in soup.select('.homeTeam a', limit=limit)])
    a_teams.extend([i.text for i in soup.select('.awayTeam a', limit=limit)])



df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(team, comps, h_teams, h_scores, a_teams, a_scores, dates)),
                      columns=headers)
```

You can search and print with:

```
df[df['Team'] == 'Wolves']
print(df.to_string())
```

And get cool data:

```
df.groupby('Team').agg({'Home Score': 'mean', 'Away Score': 'mean'})                                                                                                

                Home Score  Away Score
Team                                  
Arsenal           2.105263    1.368421
Aston Villa       1.687500    1.625000
Bournemouth       1.266667    1.066667
Brighton          1.533333    1.200000
Burnley           1.642857    1.357143
Chelsea           1.900000    1.850000
Crystal Palace    1.142857    0.928571
Everton           1.375000    1.312500
Leicester         1.312500    1.750000
Liverpool         1.857143    1.761905
Man City          2.050000    1.600000
Man Utd           1.421053    0.894737
Newcastle         1.571429    0.785714
Norwich           1.642857    1.357143
Sheff Utd         1.066667    1.066667
Southampton       1.125000    2.187500
Tottenham         1.888889    1.555556
Watford           1.500000    1.125000
West Ham          1.533333    1.466667
Wolves            1.280000    1.440000
```

or

```
df[df['Away Team'] == 'Leicester'].agg({'Home Score': 'mean', 'Away Score': 'mean'})                                                                                

Home Score    0.722222
Away Score    2.388889
dtype: float64
```

Definitely Awesome. DF.T is nice and there is a df.to_sql() if you go that route. I hope my changes help, and i'm always glad to help more

Comment: How did you deduce that? I mean to ask how did you get "///json" ?

Comment: From this line in the main page source, it's getting it's data from there: <div class="js-async-include js-event-list-async-content" data-src="/football///json" data-template="Sofa.Template.templates.list.base">

Comment: Can you please help me with the code? i am a bit blank here. Thanks

Comment: I could write the whole thing for you, but if you can now get the data, can you mark this as check marked below the up/down arrows, and open a separate question. Give a few things a shot now that you have the data, i'd be happy to answer in bit and pieces, but in the spirit of stackoverflow is iterative questioning, we help, you try some stuff and ask new questions and others help too, and we get points for it

Comment: Yeah, thats not a problem, if you give me a few, i'll give you an example on how to get a piece of data from the soup to start you off. I'll comment here when i've added it

Comment: OK. Sure! My favourite team is Manchester United. For an example, You can point me to that. But, essentially I want all the data.. for all the teams in the format: rows as ["Event date", "Competition", "Home Team", "Home Score", "Away Team", "Away Score", "Score"] e.g. 31/10/2019 Premier League Chelsea 1 Manchester United 2 1-2 for years 2018 & 2019

Comment: I updated with how to grab the data in the post and look at it for you. I can add an lxml example later, but i think you might find it easier to work directly with the json

Comment: Also, I cannot chat because it says I dont have the reputation to chat.